# Android - How to display View but somehow keep a record of the id of the view once its clicked

Tags: android

I have a list of items that I get from the database and display to an Android screen.

I add the items like this:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

if ( obj != null )
                    {
                        problems.clear();
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                        {
                            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.d( "Title: " , "" + o.getString("problem_title") );       
                            Log.d( "id: " , "" + o.getString("problem_id") );                               

                            problem_title = o.getString("problem_title");
                            problem_id = o.getString("problem_id");

                            problems.add( problem_id );

//                          Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "problem title: " + problem_title );        
                            Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "problem id: " + problem_id );

                        }

                        problems.addAll(list);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                     
                    }
```

Ideally I would display the title string to the user, and keep the id of the item tracked, but hidden from the user. Is there a way to do that?

So far I only figured out how to display the id so that when the person clicks the id, I can get that value like this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) 
    {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (( TextView ) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // For now just do something simple like display a responsive message
      Log.d( "MyProblemsActivity" , "A choice was made from the list: " + (( TextView ) view).getText() );
    }
  });
```

But is there a way to display the item string, but still be able to know what the id was when the item was clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You could modify your Adapter / List to take some custom Object and

```
static class Item {
    public String title;
    public String id;
}

List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

// inside your OnItemClickListener
adapter.getItem(position)
```

Edit:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html has a nice example.

Comment: can I still do this if I was originally using the ArrayAdapter? Or how should I change my code? Thanks!

Comment: You should change your to like in http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterown - That way you can display whatever you like (title) and have all the other data hidden (id). Another way would be to have 2 Lists. You put title in one and id in the other - use the title list with your adapter to display the titles and the other one just from onClick to get the id (lists should be the same index for matching title - id)